In Python, what is the passing logic of `sys.path` while importing a file or package?
In a __init__.py file of a package, I imported several files relying on a third party module in another path. To inform python of the path of the third party module, I add the path to sys.path, like this
# __init__.py
import sys
sys.path.append("path of the third party module")

from .file_in_the_package import ... # the file rely on the third party module

Every thing goes fine until I moved the sys.path.append to a separated file in the package, like this
# separated file imp.py
import sys
sys.path.append("path of the third party module")

# changed __init__.py
import imp
from .file_in_the_package import ... # the file rely on the third party module

in which the added "path of the third party module" can not be found in either __init__.py or file_in_the_package.py.
However, things goes fine with from .imp import *.
Now, I'm just curious that in what situation the changed sys.path will be passed when import a file/package with sys.path changed?

Generally, I advise to not modify sys.path in a Python program. Use the PYTHONPATH environment variable and adjust it to include the relevant path, or (best option) make sure the packages are installed in default locations, so that Python finds them without a problem. A virtual environment helps with this (also when developing code that is installed in "editable" mode).

What happens if you use from . import imp instead of import imp?

from . import imp also works. @9769953

Then it's the absolute import import imp that doesn't work. Which is perhaps not surprising, because that actual directory containing the file imp.py wouldn't be in sys.path, but one directory up. Alternatively, you can use import mypackage.imp as imp or from mypackage import imp or similar.

@9769953 Got it. I just want to make sure nothing strange will happen later when I'm coding. About why I use sys.path rather than PYTHONPATH, I'm just trying to separate my project into multiple git repos to manage the commit and versions separately, and I plan to link repos in different folders with sys.path. It is just a runtime environment path modification, and there will be many combinations of versions/branches of repos, so creating environments one by one may be troublesome. I don't know whether it will cause more trouble, may be there will be better solutions?

I think that Python packages shouldn't know or care about their git repositories, or how their sources are structured. I would then have each separate git repository install as a separate package, or simply have a mono-repo of all the code. There are of course git submodules, but from what I hear and read, these can be tricky to manage.

"I plan to link repos in different folders with sys.path": that sounds as if you are running the Python packages and modules directory from their repository directories. I would not do that: install them (in a virtual environment) as editable packages, and your whole sys.path / PYTHONPATH issues disappear.

I think you might like How can I import a module dynamically given the full path?
